# Highlighting Duplicate Clients with duplicate amounts. in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to highlight and mark in excel using VBA Clients with duplicate amounts. and example would be:

```
Client   Amount
123      $5
123      $6
456      $5
456      $9
456      $9
```

My current code would mark the example like this:

```
Client   Amount    Check
123      $5        Duplicate
123      $6        OK
456      $5        Duplicate
456      $9        Duplicate
456      $9        Duplicate
```

When actually

```
Client   Amount 
123      $5
456      $5
```

Should be marked as OK because it is not a dup amount on the same client.

My code is below.

```
'Checks For Duplicates
k = 2
Set AccClm = Range("A2:A" & rowz) ' area to check '
Set AmtClm = Range("C2:C" & rowz)
iWarnColor = xlThemeColorAccent2

Do While ws.Cells(k, 1) <> ""
Acc = ws.Cells(k, 1)
Amt = ws.Cells(k, 3)
    If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(AccClm, Acc) >= 2) And (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(AmtClm, Amt) >= 2) Then
                ws.Rows(k).Interior.ColorIndex = iWarnColor
                ws.Cells(k, 4) = "Duplicate"
            Else
                ws.Rows(k).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    End If
    k = k + 1
Loop
```

I am stuck and any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS instead of COUNTIF

```
        'Checks For Duplicates
    k = 2
    Set AccClm = Range("A2:A" & rowz) ' area to check '
    Set AmtClm = Range("C2:C" & rowz)
    iWarnColor = xlThemeColorAccent2

    Do While ws.Cells(k, 1) <> ""
    Acc = ws.Cells(k, 1)
    Amt = ws.Cells(k, 3)
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(AccClm, Acc, AmtClm, Amt) >= 2 Then
                    ws.Rows(k).Interior.ColorIndex = iWarnColor
                    ws.Cells(k, 4) = "Duplicate"
                Else
                    ws.Rows(k).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        End If
        k = k + 1
    Loop
```

Comment: BINGO! thanks man my mind was turning to mush and i just couldn't see it